# Is it possible to equal/overwrite one function/method with another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible if I wanted to replace/overwrite B() to C() or D() when B() is called in Form1_Load();

```
    public Prototype()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        C();
    }        

    private void Form1_Load()
    {
        B();
    }

    private void B()
    { 
        //blank so far
        //not sure what to put 
    }

    private void C()  
    {
        if (RadioButton.Checked == false)
        { B() == D(); }
        else 
        { B() == E(); }        
    }
    private void D()
    {
        //something ongoing
    }
    private void E()
    {
        //something ongoing
    }
```

basically I needed C() to act like instructor to instruct when Form1_Load() is calling B(), it's capable to say Form1_Load() actually need to call D() or E() base on situation.

I was trying to avoid too many if..else in each method. 
Basically, I am developing a software to receive multiple format csv source file and the Form1_Load() is coded to execute a set of fix instructions which involving chart building and graph plotting. I tried to make it like the skeleton for the software.

C() is use to determine the type of csv files that had been loaded by user, and decide whether it will overwrite B() with D() if its type A , else overwrite B() to E() if it's type B. 
I need to use different sets of dataset to display the csv information to chart and based on what is in the csv file I need to design different filters out relevant display.

```
    public void I1_ChartTabulate()
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        Charting.dataGridView1.DataSource = G_BS_I1;
        Charting.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[8].Visible = true;  
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[17].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[18].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[19].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[20].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[21].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[22].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[23].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[24].Visible = true;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[25].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[26].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView1.Columns[27].Visible = false;

        timer.Stop();
        label62.Text = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.00 'milliseconds'");
    }

    public void I2_ChartTabulate()
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        Charting.dataGridView2.DataSource = G_BS_I2;
        Charting.dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[1].Visible = true;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[6].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[8].Visible = true;  
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[16].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[17].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[18].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[19].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[20].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[21].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[22].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[23].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[24].Visible = true;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[25].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[26].Visible = false;
        Charting.dataGridView2.Columns[27].Visible = false;

        timer.Stop();
        label63.Text = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.00 'milliseconds'");

    }
```

To be more precise, D() and E() is not just one method, it's representing a series of methods involved to process the csv.

Comment: I think the requirement is simple and you are complicating something, could you please more clear about the requirement? how to determine `D() or E() `  what is the purpose of ` C();` in this screen

Comment: I was trying to avoid too many if..else in each method.

Comment: what are the possible different conditions that you try to avoid to check with if and else?

Comment: I was trying to avoid too many if..else in each method.

basically, I am developing a software to receive multiple format csv source file and the Form1_Load() is coded to execute a set of fix instructions which involving chart building and graph plotting.

C() is use to determine the type of csv files loaded, where it will overwrite B() with D() if its the first type, overwrite B() to E() if it's the second type.

I need to use different sets of dataset to display the csv information to chart and based on what is in the csv file I need to filter out relevant display

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do:

```
private void B()
{ 
    if(RadioButton.Checked == false) c();
    else d();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without this much of methods you can simply do the same by using the following code,

```
private void Form1_Load()
{
    if (RadioButton.Checked)
       SomeMethod_E();
    else
       SomeMethod_D();
}
```

Few  note to your Knowledge:

you should use meaningful variable names, follow Proper naming [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx), Which improves the readability of your code as well as for later modifications.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want/need but one solution is to use a delegate.
Here is a simple example:

```
    private VoidDelegate B;
    delegate void VoidDelegate();

    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        B = D;
    }

    private void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        B = E;
    }

    private void Button3Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        B();
    }

    private void D() {
        MessageBox.Show("D");
    }

    private void E() {
        MessageBox.Show("E");
    }
```

Pressing Button 1 or 2 points B to different methods and then you just run B() on Button3Click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) for these kind of purpose, especially [`Action` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) is suitable in your case:

```
private Action B;

private void Form1_Load()
{
    if(B != null)
    {
        B();
    }
}

private void C()  
{
    if (RadioButton.Checked == false)
    { B = D; }
    else 
    { B = E; }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're thinking of is called [First-Class Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), and unfortunately it's not something that C# supports, but you can still do it using a [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173171.aspx) - the only catch is you'll need to make sure you're always asigning a default action to the delegate (which your code sample would always do anyway)

```
private Action B;

private void Form1_Load()
{
    B();
}


private void C()  
{
    if (RadioButton.Checked == false) { B = D; }
    else { B = E; }        
}
```

It's also kind of related to [Event Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx), which you've probably used before.